# Websockets in Spring using Stomp - subscribe to feed

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I am looking at Websockets within a Spring application. Without going into detail of what I have written, I would like to know if what I want to do is possible and if it is sensible. They can be different.

So using the Spring guide - Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application - as a base, I wnated to have a form that takes a message (breaking news) and for other pages within the application that have subscribed to the feed to receive that breaking news.

I used Vue js for the javascript (which is not used by the guide).

The result is that though the message is displayed immediately in the form page before the submit (due to using v-model in vue), the breaking news is not shown on the other pages, though they appear to have subscribed (looking at the console output).

But the key questions are - is this possible / sensible?

Regards

Comment: with other pages, you mean the same client? Or other clients currently connected to your application? I assume you write a Single Page Application with Vue

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Various isolation problems. Vue is being used on existing web pages so not SPA. I have edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: Actually I did not edit the question as I have been playing around with the Spring Guide example and I have got that to do what I wanted.